# Microsoft Edge force HTTP/2 usage

Tags: ssl, nginx, microsoft-edge, http2

Im testing my web application with HTTP/2 protocol. Im using my local nginx with self signed ssl cert. On Google Chrome and Firefox there is no issue, the problem arises with Microsoft Edge.

Microsoft Edge is supporting HTTP/2. From this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn905221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx we can see that it will fallback to older versions when "Microsoft Edge will fall back to HTTP/1.1 when HTTP/2 is not available or the connection is not secure."

When im using it it always fallbacks to HTTP/1.1, is there a way to force HTTP/2 ? Im using Windows 10. I tried disabling ssl cert checks in internet options, i dont get warnings anymore but it still falls back.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Chrome/Firefox support NPN for HTTP/2 negotiations even though NPN is not officially part of the HTTP/2 standard. Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10 only supports ALPN. Chrome has previously stated that they intend to remove NPN. http://blog.chromium.org/2015/02/hello-http2-goodbye-spdy-http-is_9.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to force it to HTTP/2. 
But it is supported as you can see by testing this : https://http2.golang.org/gophertiles?latency=0

There may be an issue with your server config.

Comment: yes, i know it is supported. I confirmed it with couple of tests like the one you provided. I think my configuration is correct, as it works on all other browsers. The only thing different is that i use self-signed certificate, do you think this might be the issue, even tho i added this cert as trusted ? "or the connection is not secure." from MSDN - might be the reasoning behind this.